# The original state instance has the wrong type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I get the exception: `InvalidOperationException: The original state instance has the wrong type.` when using a version of the following cut down code:

```
Table existing = context.Tables.Single(t => t.Key == derivedFromTable.Key);

context.Tables.Attach((Table)derivedFromTable, existing); //thrown here

context.SubmitChanges();
```

Where `derivedFromTable is DerivedFromTable` and `class DerivedFromTable : Table`.

What does this exception mean (as clearly `((Table)derivedFromTable) is Table` and `existing is Table`) and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(Table)derivedFromTable` cast is meaningless, because the `Attach()` method already accepts an argument of type `Table` so the widening cast is implicit.

That doesn't matter, however, because Linq to SQL checks the type of the passed in object dynamically, and basically it doesn't support treating derived types as if they were the base entity (also because casting does not change the actual type of the instance, it just changes its static interface). So if you want to do this, you'll need to first copy the properties of the derived instance to an instance of the base type using something like AutoMapper. Example:

```
Table existing = context.Tables.Single(t => t.Key == derivedFromTable.Key);
Table table = Mapper.Map<DerivedFromTable, Table>(derivedFromTable);
context.Tables.Attach(table , existing);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks! Luckily my `Table` class contains a constructor which takes type `Table` so now I have `var updated = new Table(derivedFromTable)` then do `Attach(updated, existing)`.

Comment: ...which doesn't work... I think I'm going to have to go down your mapper route.

Comment: Thanks for the accept... not sure why your solution wouldn't work, unless the copy constructor doesn't function properly or something. If you use AutoMapper make sure to do `Mapper.CreateMap<DerivedFromTable, Table>()` at some point during application startup otherwise your map won't be initialized and you'll get an error when attempting to call `Mapper.Map<DerivedFromTable, Table>()`

Comment: If you're using AutoMapper, I don't know. I just made up a quick example locally and AutoMapper definitely gives back an instance of the base type when I do `Mapper.Map<Derived, Base>(derived)`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that previous comment as your previous comment didn't come up and answered it before I asked it!